# Filter by Groups in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a large dataset of claims data. I would like to filter out multiple claims from the same claimant (i.e. `ExternalLeaveId1`) based on the maximum `MaxApprovedDate` and the minimum `MinApprovedDate`.

For example, in excel I have the following:

```
  ExternalLeaveId1   WorkTypeDescription   MinApprovedDate   MaxApprovedDate
   112                Continuous            9/10/2017         9/18/2017
   112                Continuous            8/30/2017         10/10/2017
   112                Continuous            10/1/2017         10/2/2017
   112                Continuous            8/30/2017         10/9/2017
```

I would like to filter an only show the second row which has the min approved date and max approved date:

```
   ExternalLeaveId1   WorkTypeDescription   MinApprovedDate   MaxApprovedDate
   112                Continuous            8/30/2017         10/10/2017
```

Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a a group by 'ExternalLeaveId1', after converting the 'Date' columns to `Date` class, then do the `filter` by using `==`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with('Date')), mdy) %>%
    group_by(ExternalLeaveId1) %>%
    filter(MinApprovedDate == min(MinApprovedDate), 
           MaxApprovedDate == max(MaxApprovedDate)) 
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   ExternalLeaveId1 [1]
#  ExternalLeaveId1 WorkTypeDescription MinApprovedDate MaxApprovedDate
#            <int> <chr>               <date>          <date>         
#1            112 Continuous          2017-08-30      2017-10-10
```

Or another option is `slice`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(ExternalLeaveId1) %>% 
   slice(intersect(which.min(mdy(MinApprovedDate)), 
                   which.max(mdy(MaxApprovedDate))))
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   ExternalLeaveId1 [1]
#  ExternalLeaveId1 WorkTypeDescription MinApprovedDate MaxApprovedDate
#             <int> <chr>               <chr>           <chr>          
#1              112 Continuous          8/30/2017       10/10/2017
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[intersect(which.min(as.IDate(MinApprovedDate, "%m/%d/%Y")), 
       which.max(as.IDate(MaxApprovedDate, "%m/%d/%Y")))], by = ExternalLeaveId1]
#   ExternalLeaveId1 WorkTypeDescription MinApprovedDate MaxApprovedDate
#1:              112          Continuous       8/30/2017      10/10/2017
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ExternalLeaveId1 = c(112L, 112L, 112L, 112L), 
    WorkTypeDescription = c("Continuous", "Continuous", "Continuous", 
    "Continuous"), MinApprovedDate = c("9/10/2017", "8/30/2017", 
    "10/1/2017", "8/30/2017"), MaxApprovedDate = c("9/18/2017", 
    "10/10/2017", "10/2/2017", "10/9/2017")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```